# How to run a npm script after main npm script fails?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

My main npm script is "npm run build".

What I want to do is write another script that would execute like a catch in exception handling whenever "npm run build" fails.

Answer (score 6):

You can utilize the [OR operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) (`||`) in an npm script. It is supported by both `sh` and `cmd.exe` so it works cross-platform.

Consider the following example in the `scripts` section of *package.json*:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "<your build script here> || npm run fallback",
  "fallback": "echo \"Oops! Running another script....\""
},
```

**Explanation:**

1. Your current build script command should replace the `<your build script here>` part in the `build` script.
2. The `fallback` script will only run if your build command on the left side of the `||` operator exits with a non-zero exit status (i.e. if it fails).
3. When your build script command exits successfully (i.e. with a zero exit code) the `npm run fallback` part on the right side of the `||` operator never gets invoked.
4. The `"echo \"Oops! Running another script....\""` in the `fallback` script should be replaced with the command(s) that you want to execute when `build` fails.

The example above utilizes another script named `fallback` mainly for explanatory purposes, however you can just have one `build` script, For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "<your build script here> || echo \"Oops! Running another script...\""
},
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I want to run a database migration after my test script in both cases (tests fail and tests succeed). I therefore have a `posttest` script and added `|| npm run posttest` to my `test` script.